# How to check an object class within an other object

Tags: php

I’m just learning `OOP` Php, I understand the basic principles of `OOP` programming, and trying to do exercises. I wanna do a simple messaging application, where users can message each other. Like email, but in a closed system.

My idea is when an user logs in, i create an user object that contains the function that an user can do and if an admin logs in i create an admin object that extends the user class with added admin functions.

My question is Can I check in other class if the object is an admin or an user class without injecting in the classes or create the objects inside the checking class. Like this:

```
  class Checker{
      // some variables
      public function isAdmin($object ){
                if($object istanceof Admin){
                    return 1;
                 } else{
                    return 0;
                 }
           }
      }
```

Comment: yes, if you correct two typos: `istanceof` -> `instanceof`, and two missing `;` after `return 1;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO using reflection and introspection for non-debug purposes is an anti-practice.
[PHP 5 Reflection API performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294582/php-5-reflection-api-performance)

Do it like this:

```
class User implements SystemUserInterface
{
    public function isAdmin()
    {
        return false;
    }
}

class Admin extends User
{
    public function isAdmin()
    {
         return true;
    }
    // other stuff that only admin can do..
}

function checkUser($user)
{
   echo "You have created ".($user->isAdmin()? "admin":"regular")." user";
}
```